# What is the most efficient method of creating the following query in MSAccess?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I want to convert this table/query

```
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
| tag_id | attribute_name  | attribute_value |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      1 | tag_name        | P1001           |
|      1 | tag_address     | N7:0            |
|      1 | tag_description | Pump 1 Status   |
|      2 | tag_name        | P1002           |
|      2 | tag_address     | N7:1            |
|      2 | tag_description | Pump 2 Status   |
|      3 | tag_name        | P1003           |
|      3 | tag_address     | N7:2            |
|      3 | tag_description | Pump 3 Status   |
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

to this

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| tag_name | tag_address | tag_description |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| P1001    | N7:0        | Pump 1 Status   |
| P1002    | N7:1        | Pump 2 Status   |
| P1003    | N7:2        | Pump 3 Status   |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I know the cross-tab query exists but it forces me to pick an aggregate function for the Value. If I choose `First` or `Max` it works but it doesn't feel like the most efficient way of doing it. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
select tag_name, tag_address, tag_description from
(
    (
        select tag_id, attribute_value as tag_name
        from inputtable
        where attribute_name='tag_name'
    ) as one
    left join
    (
        select tag_id, attribute_value as tag_address
        from inputtable
        where attribute_name='tag_address'
    ) as two
    on one.tag_id=two.tag_id
)
left join
(
    select tag_id, attribute_value as tag_description
    from inputtable
    where attribute_name='tag_description'
) as three
on one.tag_id=three.tag_id
```

Comment: Access won't like that query. It will throw a syntax error due to lack of parentheses around the first pair of joined subqueries. (Access is kind of fussy about that.)

Comment: Ah... I'm more of a SQL Server guy. Fixed. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested in your question,

```sql
TRANSFORM MAX(attribute_value) AS thing
SELECT tag_id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY tag_id
PIVOT attribute_name IN ('tag_name','tag_address','tag_description')
```

will work. Another alternative would be

```sql
SELECT tn.tag_name, ta.tag_address, td.tag_description
FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                tag_id, 
                attribute_value AS tag_name
            FROM your_table
            WHERE attribute_name = 'tag_name'
        ) AS tn
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                tag_id, 
                attribute_value AS tag_address
            FROM your_table
            WHERE attribute_name = 'tag_address'
        ) AS ta
            ON ta.tag_id = tn.tag_id
    )
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            tag_id, 
            attribute_value AS tag_description
        FROM your_table
        WHERE attribute_name = 'tag_description'
    ) AS td
        ON td.tag_id = tn.tag_id
```

but I'd probably just go with the first one.